# Arangodump fails 'Could not connect to endpoint' message

Tags: arangodb

I am using Arangodb community edition

- version 3.6.1
- rockdb
- single instance

And I am trying to backup the db using the following command

```
arangodump --output-directory "dump" --overwrite true --server.database "xxx"
```

I am logged in at the root user on the server and get the following error message.

[79856] ERROR [775bd] {dump} Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529'

[79856] ERROR [b1ad6] {dump} Error message: 'Connection closed by remote'

Also can you suggest any other backup/restore methods available for community edition users?

Comment: What protocols and ports do you have arango bound to in your arangod.conf? in particular, for 127.0.0.1

Comment: the reference to any binding I can find is "endpoint = ssl://[::]:8529" do I need to add one for tcp?

Comment: usually i keep 8529 for tcp, and 8530 for ssl. you'll need to set up a tcp port in order to use tcp, and ssl is dedicated to ssl connections, which you'll also need to provide a .pem file for the ssl binding to use.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DavidThomas. I got this working by using the --server.endpoint option. I set the value to ssl://127.0.0.1:8529 and it worked a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the endpoint from `tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`
to `ssl://127.0.0.1:8529`

did the trick for me